# Why doe the AFCI immediately trip?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, afci

I move an outlet 12" and rewired it the exact same; now the AFCI trips immediately, when turning the power back on.  It's a 14/ wire in sequence with a pig tail to the outlet.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Obviously something changed. A picture or wiring diagram would help figure out just what.

Comment: If you wired it the same you might have skinned the insulation causing the problem, my apprentice did something like this with a metal box. I opened up the boxes and found a arc mark, insulated with electrical tape and it has been fine since then.

Answer (score 1):

An immediate trip typically points to a short-circuit. Make sure that when you pushed the receptacle into place none of the wires came loose, and that the grounding conductor did not contact the ungrounded (hot) terminal on the receptacle.